# How to enable HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

It would be really helpful if anyone suggest me to enable HSTS in sonarqube

I have tried the same in Jenkins and It's working as expected, as there is plugin called HSTS Filter Plugin available in Jenkins.

Please suggest if there is any plugin available in sonarqube, if not then how to change the configuration to work with HSTS.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no extension points, so no plugins, for changing HTTP headers. The solution is to deploy SonarQube server behind a reverse-proxy like Apache or nginx.